# Short story - immortal hero with a metal staff

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in the early 80s, probably in a collection or anthology of some sort. The hero is a very large but aging man, who wields a solid metal quarterstaff that he crushes his foes with.

At the start of the story I think he was beginning to show his age, but the mysterious beings he served renewed his immortality by commanding him to embrace a large metal sphere which very painfully rejuvenated him to a younger and stronger state.  They had done this to him many times before.

My impression is that the setting was either prehistoric Earth (similar to Howard's *Hyborean Age*, or Clark Ashton Smith's *Hyperborea*) or a very far future Jack Vance *Dying Earth*-type place.

It seemed like this was an introductory story to a series, but I don't recall ever seeing the character again.

I've ruled out the first couple of *Thieves' World* books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character is Amalric The Mangod, in the story "The Higher Heresies of Oolimar", in the anthology [*Flashing Swords! 1*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashing_Swords!_1).  The story does indeed open with the near immortal Amalric being summoned by the gods to a sphere in the mountains.  Embracing the sphere allows him to commune with the gods and to restore his youth.

Comment: That's the one, thanks.  I even own a copy of *Flashing Sword #1*, somewhere. The author is Lin Carter, which explains why it was reminiscent of Howard, etc.